# Is it normal if www-data user run more than 1

Tags: linux, apache2, www-data

Today I track my server performance and I found that www-data user is running more than 1 and it use a lot of cpu usage. Can I know is it normal? and if it is not normal can you guys suggest what should I do to reduce my cpu usage? 
[refer this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ryvjz.png)

Comment: more than one of processes?

Comment: @asdmin yess it shows 3 process sometimes and it use a lot of cpu usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is standard apache2 web server. What you can check is the error log, access log. Also check if some king of scripting language like php, perl run on this web site and check the code.

Without more information we can hardly provide more recommendations.